# How to use order by in Big Object Query?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, big-object

I am trying to query records from big object in a list, using the following query

```sql
Select Edit_Date__c ,CreatedDate,Field__c ,Loan_ID__c ,New_Value__c ,Old_Value__c ,User__c, System_Updates__c, Audit_ID__c FROM Loan_Audit__b limit 1000
```

I want to return most recent created records in the list using the above query. The above query is not allowing me to add  `ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC`  so that i can sort the records as the latest created records appers first.Please provide me some solution or any workarounds to sort this records.

Comment: Can you post the error message you are getting?

Comment: field 'CreatedDate' can not be sorted in a query call
I am getting this error when i tried this query
Select Edit_Date__c ,CreatedDate,Field__c ,Loan_ID__c ,New_Value__c ,Old_Value__c ,User__c, System_Updates__c, Audit_ID__c FROM Loan_Audit__b order by CreatedDate limit 1000;

Comment: Have you tried using Edit_Date__c for sorting, to see if it's supported.

Comment: yes i have tried order by with all the fields that i have in big object

Comment: AFAIK, maybe it's because the date field is not indexed, or you need to use as an async SOQL or you need to check if that aggregate function is supported.

Comment: did it solve your problem? Please mark if as so.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Order By` on the big object field, but this field should be a part of index and also it should be the first index key.

We can make any 5 field as index in big object. But the field using which you want to sort `Order By` the records in query should be the first index key field.

I have used the following query;

```
SELECT  CreatedById, CreatedDate, SystemModstamp, AlternateNumber__c, Blockname__c FROM BObject__b order by Blockname__c
```

Here in this query, `Blockname__c` is my first index field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your query as async SOQL and index the field you are querying. Aggregate functions are only supported then.

[Implementation guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/async_query_running_queries.htm)